# Numeric Data Types in Postgre SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

When I am writing code for postgre sql. I often get unwanted numeric type especially in the '0.12E3' decimal form.

For example,

```
with data as (
select created_at::timestamp::date as date,count(*)
from posts
group by created_at::timestamp::date
)
select date, count, sum(count) over
(order by date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as total
from data
```

This code gives me the result of the cumulative sum in the form of scientific notation.

Why does this happen even if there is no float in the code? And how can I make it right or avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an alias when you use a agragate -- like this:

```
with data as (
  select created_at::timestamp::date as date, count(*) as day_count
  from posts
  group by created_at::timestamp::date
)
select date, day_count, 
       sum(day_count) over (order by date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as total
from data
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer Hogan, but do you also mind telling me the reason behind this happening though?